# Unable to cast object while cast two identical object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, casting

In my model i have three identical class (Views, UViews, TotalConfiguration and StatsViewModel). Each of them has the same identical properties:

```
 public class Views
    {
        public int idProject {get;set;}
        public int January { get; set; }
        public int February { get; set; }
        public int March { get; set; }
        public int April { get; set; }
        public int May { get; set; }
        public int June { get; set; }
        public int July { get; set; }
        public int August { get; set; }
        public int September { get; set; }
        public int October { get; set; }
        public int November { get; set; }
        public int December { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get data from database (from Views or UViews or TotalConfiguration) via context and save result to List type StatsViewModel:

```
//some code

var customer = _context.Get<UViews>(x => x.Projects.ProjectsUser.Where(x => x.IdUser == userId).Any());

//some code

public StatsViewModel Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
   where T : class
        {
            List<StatsViewModel> listItem = new List<StatsViewModel>();
            StatsViewModel item = new StatsViewModel();

            var listFromDatabase = Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
            listItem.AddRange(listFromDatabase.Cast<StatsViewModel>());

            item = listItem.FirstOrDefault();
            return item;
        }
```

Code work perfect to line `listItem.AddRange(listFromDatabase.Cast<StatsViewModel>());`. When i try convert **listFromDatabase** to **listItem** i got error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object 
of type 'Housematica.Data.Data.CMS.Statistics.UViews' 
to type 'Housematica.Intranet.ViewModel.StatsViewModel'.'
```

I try do something like this, but in this case i got this same error:

```
var listFromDatabase = Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList().Cast<StatsViewModel>();
```

Comment: C# doesn't do duck typing. It's not sufficient that objects of different classes have the same properties - they're still different types. You might be looking for something like Automapper.

Comment: From the compiler-perspective your three types have nothing in common. From a *semantic* perspective however... You may introduce a custom cast-operator and use `Select(x => (MyType)x)` instead of `.Cast<T>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `Cast<T>` basically does `(MyType)x` internally anyway.

Comment: @DavidG also for user-defined casts? I suspect it does not.

Comment: @HimBromBeere What do you mean by "user-defined casts"? I was talking about [`Cast<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Cast.cs#L52)

Comment: @DavidG I know, however I´m unsure if `Cast<T>` also handles `static implicit/explicit operator ClassA(ClassB b)`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Oh I see, well no, it doesn't handle it because of the generic nature of `Cast`, it hides the fact that an implicit cast is available from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a compiler-perspective those types don´t have **anything** in common. Only because two types have identical properties doesn´t make them equal types. This becomes more clear as classes usually also have **methods**. How would you ever indicate two classes two have the same method? Imagine these two:

```
class ClassA
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
    void DoSomething() => { Console.WriteLine(MyProperty); }
}
class ClassB
{
    int MyProperty { get; set; }
    void DoSomething() => { Console.WriteLine("Hello world"); }
}
```

Are the above two classes equivalent because they have the same members? Hard to tell. Of course their properties match, but what about their methods? Are those two equivalent? Well, from a formal perspective only considering their signature one might assume so. However they do comppelety different things. So it´s impossible for the compiler to make assumptions about if your two types actually represent the same thing, which is why it does not (implictely) allow for such a conversion.

However there are many other opportunitites for you. The easiest would be to create some mapping-function:

```
ClassA Map(ClassB b) => new ClassA { MyProperty = b.MyProperty };
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
myList.Select(x => Map(x));
```

Another way would be a copy-constructor:

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(ClassB b) { this.MyProerty = b.MyProperty }
}
```

which you can call with this `Select`-statement:

```
myList.Select(x => new ClassA(x));
```

Finally you could introduce some implicit or explicit conversion:

```
static explicit operator ClassA(ClassB b) => new ClassA { MyProperty = b.MyProperty };
```

which is the only one you could use with a cast:

```
myList.Select(x => (ClassA)x);
```

However be aware that calling the generic `Cast<T>` from `IEnumerable<T>` won´t reflect user-defined casts. so the following still does not work on any of the three forementioned solutions:

```
myList.Cast<ClassA>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found something like JsonConvert and I use this in my code:

```
public StatsViewModel Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
   {
      StatsViewModel item = new StatsViewModel();
      var listFromDatabase = Set<T>().Where(predicate).ToList();
            
      List<StatsViewModel> targetlst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StatsViewModel>>
      (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listFromDatabase));

      item = targetlst.FirstOrDefault();
      return item;
   }
```